# $f(x) = 2^\alpha x^2+2^\beta x - 2^\gamma=y^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations

A few questions regarding a polynomial of degree 2:

$f(x) = ax^2 + bx - c$

where $a,b,c$ are given positive powers of 2.

Or more explicitly:

$f(x) = 2^\alpha x^2+2^\beta x - 2^\gamma$

where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are positive integers

1) Can one theoretically (I mean not by an algorithm which include any trial and error parts) determine if there is a positive integer value $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)$ is a square (namely that there is a positive integer $y$ such that $f(x_0)=y^2$) depending on the values of $a,b,c$?

2) Can one generate all solutions given one solution?

3) Given there is a solution, is there an algorithm to yield the solution?

Thanks

Comment: $f(x)=y^2$ can be written as 
$$(2^{\frac{\alpha}2}x+2^{\beta-1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}-y)(2^{\frac{\alpha}2}x+2^{\beta-1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}+y)=2^{2\beta-\alpha-2}+2^{\gamma}$$
So, if $\alpha$ is even $(\alpha=2m)$ and $2\beta-\alpha-2\ge 0$, then every integer solution (if any) is of the form
$x=(s^2+2^{2\beta-\alpha-2}+2^{\gamma}-2^{\beta-m}s)/(2^{m+1}s)$,$y=(2^{2\beta-\alpha-2}+2^{\gamma}-s^2)/(2s)$ where $s$ is a divisor of $2^{2\beta-\alpha-2}+2^{\gamma}$.

Answer (score -1):

If so we can write
$$2^{\alpha}x^2+2^{\beta}x-2^{\gamma}=(Ax+B)^2$$
so we get
$$2^{\alpha}=A^2$$
$$2AB=2^{\beta}$$
$$-2^{\gamma}=B^2$$
The last equation isn't fulfilled for any real number $$\gamma,B$$

Comment: consider $\alpha,\beta = 1, \gamma=3,x=2$ we get $2^1 2^2 + 2^1 2 - 2^3 = 4 = 2^2$

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but I think this proves that the polynomials on the left and right of the first equation are never equal. The question is actually if they intersect on some integer values for $A,B,\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ where also $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are positive